# Show captcha when unexpected navigation detected to prevent traffic abuse

Tags: php, jquery, captcha, web-traffic

I noticed that some user overloading my website by downloading multiple files (for example 500 files at same time) and opening more pages in small duration, I want to show **captcha** if unexpected navigation detected by user.

I know how to implement **Captcha**, but I can't figure out what is the best approach to detect traffic abuse using (PHP)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A common approach is to use something like memcached to store the requests on a minute basis, I have open sourced a small class that achieves this: [php-ratelimiter](https://github.com/akirk/php-ratelimiter)

If you are interested in a more thorough explanation of why the requests need to be stored on a minute basis, [check this post](http://alexander.kirk.at/2013/04/19/add-a-rate-limit-to-your-website/).

So to sum it up, your code could end up looking like this:

```
if (!verifyCaptcha()) {
    $rateLimiter = new RateLimiter(new Memcache(), $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
    try {
        $rateLimiter->limitRequestsInMinutes(100, 5);
    } catch (RateExceededException $e) {
        displayCaptcha();
        exit;
    }
}
```

Actually, the code is based on a per-minute basis but you can quite easily adapt this to be on a per 30 seconds basis:

```
private function getKeys($halfminutes) {
    $keys = array();
    $now = time();
    for ($time = $now - $halfminutes * 30; $time <= $now; $time += 30) {
        $keys[] = $this->prefix . date("dHis", $time);
    }
    return $keys;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Introduction**

A similar question has be answered before [Prevent PHP script from being flooded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10155339/prevent-php-script-from-being-flooded) but it might not be sufficient reasons :

- It uses `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]` and they are some shared connection have the same `Public IP Address`
- There are so many `Firefox addon` that can allows users to use multiple proxy for each request

**Multiple Request != Multiple Download**

Preventing multiple request is totally different from Multiple Download why ?

Lest Imagine a file of `10MB` that would take `1min` to download ,  If you limit users to say `100 request per min`  what it means you are given access to the user to download

```
10MB * 100 per min
```

To fix this issue you can look at [Download - max connections per user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902129/download-max-connections-per-user/12902731#12902731).

**Multiple Request**

Back to page access you can use `SimpleFlood` which extend `memcache` to limit users per second. It uses `cookies` to resolve the shared connection issue and attempts to get the real IP address

```
$flood = new SimpleFlood();
$flood->addserver("127.0.0.1"); // add memcache server
$flood->setLimit(2); // expect 1 request every 2 sec
try {
    $flood->check();
} catch ( Exception $e ) {
    sleep(2); // Feel like wasting time 
    // Display Captcher
    // Write Message to Log
    printf("%s => %s %s", date("Y-m-d g:i:s"), $e->getMessage(), $e->getFile());
}
```

Please note that `SimpleFlood::setLimit(float $float);` accepts floats so you can have

```
$flood->setLimit(0.1); // expect 1 request every 0.1 sec
```

**Class Used**

```
class SimpleFlood extends \Memcache {
    private $ip;
    private $key;
    private $prenalty = 0;
    private $limit = 100;
    private $mins = 1;
    private $salt = "I like TO dance A #### Lot";

    function check() {
        $this->parseValues();
        $runtime = floatval($this->get($this->key));
        $diff = microtime(true) - $runtime;
        if ($diff < $this->limit) {
            throw new Exception("Limit Exceeded By :  $this->ip");
        }
        $this->set($this->key, microtime(true));
    }

    public function setLimit($limit) {
        $this->limit = $limit;
    }

    private function parseValues() {
        $this->ip = $this->getIPAddress();
        if (! $this->ip) {
            throw new Exception("Where the hell is the ip address");
        }

        if (isset($_COOKIE["xf"])) {
            $cookie = json_decode($_COOKIE["xf"]);
            if ($this->ip != $cookie->ip) {
                unset($_COOKIE["xf"]);
                setcookie("xf", null, time() - 3600);
                throw new Exception("Last IP did not match");
            }

            if ($cookie->hash != sha1($cookie->key . $this->salt)) {
                unset($_COOKIE["xf"]);
                setcookie("xf", null, time() - 3600);
                throw new Exception("Nice Faking cookie");
            }
            if (strpos($cookie->key, "floodIP") === 0) {
                $cookie->key = "floodRand" . bin2hex(mcrypt_create_iv(50, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));
            }
            $this->key = $cookie->key;
        } else {
            $this->key = "floodIP" . sha1($this->ip);
            $cookie = (object) array(
                    "key" => $this->key,
                    "ip" => $this->ip
            );
        }
        $cookie->hash = sha1($this->key . $this->salt);
        $cookie = json_encode($cookie);
        setcookie("xf", $cookie, time() + 3600); // expire in 1hr
    }

    private function getIPAddress() {
        foreach ( array(
                'HTTP_CLIENT_IP',
                'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR',
                'HTTP_X_FORWARDED',
                'HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP',
                'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR',
                'HTTP_FORWARDED',
                'REMOTE_ADDR'
        ) as $key ) {
            if (array_key_exists($key, $_SERVER) === true) {
                foreach ( explode(',', $_SERVER[$key]) as $ip ) {
                    if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) !== false) {
                        return $ip;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

**Conclusion**

This is a basic prove of concept and additional layers can be added to it such as

- Set different limit for differences URLS
- Add support for penalties where you block user for certain number of Mins or hours
- Detection and Different Limit for `Tor` connections
- etc

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use sessions in this case.
Initialize a session to store a timestamp[use microtime for better results] and then get timestamp of the new page.The difference can be used to analyzed the frequency of pages being visited and captcha can be shown.

You can also run a counter on pages being visited and use a 2d array to store the page and timestamp.If the value of pages being visited increases suddenly then you can check for timestamp difference.

Comment: I also tried to do it using session. after implementing it I faced some overhead during calculating number of visits and updating it for each new visit...

Comment: Well there won't be many traffic abusers i guess. You can create a database table for it and after some IPs seem secure by above calculations add them to the list.You may also add bad IPs to database with some distinguishing key.So if once you recognize some IP address as bad run calculations seldomly or instead show captcha  after every x number of page visits per ip

Comment: But, sometimes, good user wants to download list of files, but not always, that's why I need to show captcha only when unexpected behavior detected

Comment: A good user wont download too quickly and if it does you show the captcha. Increase the duration of captcha after each captcha verification if you like